Can an application control journaled filesystem?
Linux (and UNIX) filesystems featuring journaling are there to prevent filesystem corruption (any maybe file corruption, too).
Some of them have mount options to control the details of journaling, and there are some controls like O_DIRECT, O_DSYNC, or O_SYNC.
However I wonder whether an application can control journaling of its open files itself (like the mount options do).
The reason for this question is that the current OpenLDAP database (LMDB) shows poor performance on a journaled filesystem, and the recommendation is not to use a journaled filesystem.

Using a journald filesystem is known to cause a substantial performance
hit, it's in the admin guide as I previously noted.

(Message-ID: <36D8C19E8E4C73FD62A033F2@[192.168.1.89]>, about "symas2.6.7 is data transfer is faster in centos7 but very very slow in rocky8")
The cited admin guide states:

Use fast filesystems, and conduct your own testing to see which filesystem types perform best with your workload. (On our own Linux testing, EXT2 and JFS tend to provide better write performance than everything else, including newer filesystems like EXT4, BTRFS, etc.)


Which filesystem? As you note, some of them have mount options, and similarly they differ in the controls exposed to userspace. Also, data-journaled or metadata-journaled? is the main counter-question. (Ext4 works in both modes depending on distro defaults, and I can imagine that data-journal mode ruins performance but I also doubt that the exact same applies to the metadata-only-journal mode.)

@grawity Any journaled filesystem: Is there some API to control the journaling, or doesn't such exist?

@U.Windl that's impossible to know. Filesystems get developed every day, and nobody can claim they know every journaling file system on any OS. Yes, I'm pretty sure such things exist on special purpose OSes, I'm not sure (experienced enough) in Linux file systems. Every file system is free to react to ioctl calls on its files as it wants. So, yes, there's generally an API with which you could communicate such demands to your file system. If you want more specific information, you will need to be more specific.

Also note that the email incorrectly represents what is written in the admin guide. The admin guide explicitly states that things perform well on JFS – and the "J" in "JFS" stands for journalling. I think your question might be based on a misrepresentation. Also, be vary of documentation that describes EXT4 as "newer filesystem". Ext4 is 18 years old by now. Early day performance has very little to nothing to do with how it behaves today.

That sentence that ext2 behaves better than ext4 is in the documentation since OpenLDAP 2.4 – from 2007. It's basically worth nothing after 17 years – the Linux file system layer has massively evolved.

I think the basic point with all databases is that they have their own commit/rollback concept, and journaled filesystems seem to duplicate that (when the DB is flushing its buffers for a checkpoint, those changes still end up in the journal AFAIK, thus duplicating the writes unnecessarily). So being able to suspend journal writing for some files might increase the write performance.

@U.Windl in a sense, you're right, but not quite – the database does journaling (or some other form of state assurance) to make sure that even in the case of failure, the data is transactionally consistent, where a transaction is defined by e.g. the SQL query updating the data, whereas a file system metadata journal protects the file system being data-structure wise inconsistent. These two journals protect two different things! A database log entry might cover things done in zero or more file system metadata updates.

@MarcusMüller "controlling" does not mean "permanently disable", however: Consider the case where someone want to populate a database with 13 million (or so) records: Say without journaling it takes 2 hours, while with journaling it takes 6 hours. Once completed the initial loading, the journal could be turned on again. If the machine crashed during initial loading (unlikely), it's still faster to restart, rather than to wait (you might still have to restart the loading even with journaling enabled)

I think you're opening a whole barrel of hypotheticals there. Metadata journaling simply isn't that expensive. And: if you have that six hour operation, why don't you just try with a different file system. And: the first comment pointed you to mount options, already. Could have mounted a journaling file system with journaling disabled, done the import, re-mounted defaulting. But again, that's probably 100% in vain, because metadata journaling really isn't that expensive.

Yes, but ignoring mount/unmount (that a privileged application could do with different options) the question was "Can an application control journaled filesystem?" As it look now, the answer is very much "No!"
